# Excel function: If cell is equal to another cell in range, return three other items

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I am working on an excel document for meal-planning. I am trying to create a function that will allow me to search to see if the meal is in a column, and if the meal is in the column, then return the ingredients.

The first sheet looks something like this:

```
               Breakfast       Lunch          Dinner
 Monday        Cereal          PB&J
 Tuesday                                      Pizza
 Wednesday     Coffee
 Thursday                      PB&J
 Friday
```

In the second sheet, I have the recipes written like this:

```
 PB&J        Peanut Butter     Jelly     Bread
 Pizza       Cheese            Sauce     Pie Crust
```

I want to search the first sheet for all instances of a recipe, lets say PB&J. And If PB&J shows up, I want it to return Peanut Butter, Jelly, and Bread (my shopping list).

I am not sure how to write a function that may return more than one item, however. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the the number of ingredients always three or can be more with each column representing one ingredient?

Comment: It may be more depending on the recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your sheets are set up like this:

`Sheet1`:
[image]

So your days of the week and food options are at the top.

`Sheet2`, your ingredients lists, is like this:
[image]

Back on Sheet1, let's use `A7` as the food you want to look up.  In `B7`, you can use a simple `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=VLOOKUP($A7,Sheet2!$A$1:$K$3,COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

and drag right a bunch of columns.  To hide the `0` returns, just wrap the formula in an `IF` statement:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A7,Sheet2!$A$1:$K$3,COLUMN(),FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP($A7,Sheet2!$A$1:$K$3,COLUMN(),FALSE))
```

Comment: Wow this was extremely helpful, exactly what I needed to do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do. Lets say the sheet with ingredients is named 'Ingredients'. You can first check in a 'Exists' column as to whether the particular instance of recipe exists in the range. Then, if it exists another column can show the ingredients as a comma separated list.

```
Formulas:

    Recipe exists   : `=COUNTIF($B$2:$D$6,"*"&F2&"*")>0`
    Get Ingredients : `IF(G2,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,Ingredients!B1:Ingredients!D1))`

    Col F contains the recipe names, 
    Col G indicates whether the recipes exists in the range.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like your use of `TEXTJOIN()` to keep it all in one cell. Nice thinking!